# MySQL availability calendar - way to calculate free dates?

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I'm building a simple availability calendar with PHP and MySQL.

I have a table which stores the available dates for a property (currently all of them are blocks of 7 days)

```
available_dates:
    start_date    DATE
    end_date      DATE
    available_id  INT PRIMARY KEY
    property_id   INT
    booked        TINYINT(1)
```

And a table of booked dates which references the `available_id` of my `available_dates` table:

```
bookings
    booking_id INT
    available_id INT

    ***user details***
```

I plan on having rows added to available_dates for each property to mark which dates can be booked, and then setting the booked flag on that table when somebody books that block.

What I'd like to do is show a list of dates (in blocks of `x` days, 7 in this case) that have no availability set - so the date does not appear in that table - for the next 24 months or so.

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this and I ***know*** there is a simpler way to do it that my first ideas of looping through each property, then each block of 7 days, etc etc.

Can anyone enlighten me?

---

**Update:**

Thanks to @ZaneBien 's brilliant and comprehensive answer, I've managed to get the results I need by using his `yeardate` table & procedure.
What I've done is when the page that needs to show the dates with no availability set is requested, the PHP will call the procedure to add more yeardates if there aren't any for `CURYEAR()+2`.

Then to get my results, a slightly modified version of Zane's query:

```
SELECT
    a.yeardate AS blockstart,
    DATE_ADD(a.yeardate, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS blockend
FROM
    yeardates a  
LEFT JOIN
    available_dates b 
        ON(a.yeardate BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date)              
    OR      
    (DATE_ADD(a.yeardate, INTERVAL 7 DAY) BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date)
WHERE
    b.date_id IS NULL AND WEEKDAY(a.yeardate)=5;
```

In my case, the blocks are of 7 days, saturday to saturday - so I added the second `WHERE` clause to the query so that I get distinct 1 week saturday to saturday blocks for each row, that happen one after the other.

So instead of:

```
+------------+------------+
| blockstart | blockend   |
+------------+------------+
| 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-08 |
| 2012-01-02 | 2012-01-09 |
| 2012-01-03 | 2012-01-10 |
| 2012-01-04 | 2012-01-11 |
```

I get this:

```
+------------+------------+
| blockstart | blockend   |
+------------+------------+
| 2012-01-07 | 2012-01-14 |
| 2012-01-14 | 2012-01-21 |
| 2012-01-21 | 2012-01-28 |
| 2012-01-28 | 2012-02-04 |
```

Which is ***exactly*** what I need. Thanks again to Zane for a great answer.

Comment: So after a user books a date block (inserts new record into bookings table), do you immediately set the booked flag to 1 for that date? Also, what do you do if a user books say, 3 weeks? Can they? Do you insert 3 rows in the bookings table to book each of the 3 blocks?

Comment: Initially after reading your question, I thought you just wanted all records in `available_dates` that aren't booked (WHERE booked = 0, or NOT IN, etc.), but after reading it closer, I *think* what you want is all 7 day blocks out of the next two **years** that **aren't** in the `availability_dates` table. Is this correct?

Comment: @ZaneBien yes they can book >1 date and each block booked would be one row in the bookings table. And yes I know it's not the clearest question ever, the subject is rather complex (atleast to me), but you get the gist of it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding your question as *Retrieve all 7 day interval blocks of the current and next year whose ranges do not overlap any interval blocks already existing in the `available_dates` table*:

To work with all days of the current and next year, we have to create a separate table (`yeardates`) containing `DATE`s of all days of the current and next year. This will facilitate our `OUTER JOIN` operation in the retrieval query.

Code to define the `yeardates` table and insert dates:

```
CREATE TABLE yeardates 
(
    yeardate DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (yeardate)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE PopulateYear(IN inputyear INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE i INT;
        DECLARE i_end INT;
        SET i = 1;
        SET i_end = CASE WHEN inputyear % 4 THEN 365 ELSE 366 END;
        START TRANSACTION;
        WHILE i <= i_end DO
            INSERT INTO yeardates VALUES (MAKEDATE(inputyear, i));
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
        COMMIT;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL PopulateYear(2012);
CALL PopulateYear(2013);
```

The table is then created and contains all days of the current and next year. If we ever need to insert days for subsequent years, just `CALL` the procedure again with the year as the parameter (e.g. 2014, 2015, etc..).

Then we can get the 7-day blocks that don't overlap blocks in the available_dates table:

```
SELECT
    a.yeardate AS blockstart,
    DATE_ADD(a.yeardate, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS blockend
FROM
    yeardates a
LEFT JOIN 
    available_dates b ON 
        (a.yeardate BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date)
        OR
        (DATE_ADD(a.yeardate, INTERVAL 7 DAY) BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date)
WHERE
    b.available_id IS NULL
```

That retrieves all free 7-day blocks based on the bookings of *all* properties, but if we need to get the free 7-day blocks for just a particular property, we can use:

```
SELECT
    a.yeardate AS blockstart,
    DATE_ADD(a.yeardate, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS blockend
FROM
    yeardates a
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM available_dates
        WHERE property_id = <property_id here>
    ) b ON 
        (a.yeardate BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date)
        OR
        (DATE_ADD(a.yeardate, INTERVAL 7 DAY) BETWEEN b.start_date AND b.end_date)
WHERE
    b.available_id IS NULL
```

Where `<property_id here>` is the property_id. We can even do the selection based on multiple properties at a time by simply changing it to `WHERE property_id IN (<comma sep'd list of property_ids here>)`.

Comment: this is a pretty good solution, exactly what I asked for, thanks. I'll give it a shot and accept if all goes well :)

Comment: this helped me out, thanks again. I'll be doing a little modifying of the last query though, I'll update with the changes when I'm done :)

Comment: Great! I'm glad you got the results you needed. I know this is kind of nit-picky... but in your modified query, that's not really a correct use of the `HAVING` clause. It *might* be understandable if `blockstart` was a calculated value due to `HAVING` being evaluated last, but in your case, `blockstart` is just an alias for `a.yeardate` (you still have access to it, even after aliasing). The `GROUP BY` is also unnecessary since `a.yeardate` values are unique. So as a final suggestion, take out `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` and put `WEEKDAY(a.yeardate) = 5` as a second conditional check in `WHERE`.

Comment: *facepalm* no you're not being nitpicky, I completely failed to notice that. because it's aliased I somehow thought it needed grouped / having rather than just a test, I'll update that :)

Answer (score 0):

I think youve got it backwards.

All dates are potentially available unless booked, record what has been booked in the database and knock those out of your results

Comment: This is part of the issue - all dates *aren't* potentially avaialable unless booked - in this case only certain weeks of the year can be booked. Otherwise I would be doing it your way. So how should I approach it if not by recording the available dates?